# ng-repeat not updating after change in nestled data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a directive that draws something using d3.js what and if I draw it is depends on data in my scope. My problem is that I can't get it to redraw things after a change, I've tried variants with $scope.$apply and haven't had any success so far.

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="Mainctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="val in data">
    <div draw="" value="{{val.avg}}">{{val.avg}}</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);
app.controller('Mainctrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.data = 
  [{avg: 0},
  {avg: 1}];

  $timeout(function (){
    var i = 1;
      for (key in $scope.data){
         $scope.data[key].avg = i++; 
      };
    }
    ,3000)
  });

  app.directive('draw', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        value: "@"
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs){
      if (attrs.value != 0) {
      var svgContainer = d3.select(element[0]).append("svg").attr("width", 200).attr("height", 200);
      var circle = svgContainer.append("circle").attr("cx", 30).attr("cy", 30).attr("r", 20);
      }
    }
  }

 });
```

Here is a plunker with the problem reproduced: http://plnkr.co/edit/V62WngzpmsBWh6zSHCcM?

Comment: attrs.value != 0 change this to attrs.value !== 0; there were 2 other javascript warnings in js file  1. for (key in $scope.data) should be for (var key in $scope.data)

Comment: If i change it to !== it will draw the circle for 0, I want it to draw a circle for all values that's not 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your directive to:

```
 app.directive('draw', function() {
    return {
       scope: {
       value: "=" //<---
    },
  link: function (scope, element, attrs){
     scope.$watch("value", function(val) {
        //draw stuff with val
     });
  }
}
```

}

and your html to be:

```
<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="Mainctrl">
   <div ng-repeat="val in data">
     <div draw value="val.avg">{{val.avg}}</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

here is the updated plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/pIN8iy77QY5n4THqIcLp?p=preview

Comment: Thank you! Now I have the problem that it draws another circle if there already was one there, but that's another problem :)

Comment: Yes, you'd need to use d3 to update the data or just clean and draw again